# Analog Switch IC controlled with logic input

Tags: switches, analog, automotive

I want to brake the connection between 2 traces on my pcb if i need to.
the input is 12v (cars voltage 12v-14v) from the cars brake signal and the output goes to my device that uses the brake signal.
i want to be able to cut this connection so the device does not receive the brake signal anymore.

I tried to use the MAX4544 but i don't know if this is the best solution.
the problem i have with below schematic is that when COM gets 12v V+ goes from 5v to ~8v.

Maybe there is a better way to do this different ic or schematic.

I already have a opto coupler to sense the brake signal to my MCU.
Maybe its better to use this digital signal to drive a mosfet to output the 12v to device and use a analog switch to cut the digital line to the mosfet.
But i would lose the safety part to have it NC.

my knowledge it not this extended so i am
looking forward to suggestions and idea's

[image]

Comment: brake ? (to brake = remmen (Dutch) ) you mean: break the connection. You don't tell us what kind of signal you have, how much current needs to flow ? You **cannot** use (almost) any chip to switch a 5v - 8 V signal when the chip runs on 5 V. The supply voltage **MUST** always be larger than the largest voltage you're switching. I suggest **not** using a chip but to use a relay. Much easier to work with and understand. Cars are already full of relays anyway because they're robust.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an analog switch or relay that is more apropriate for the application.

The MAX4544 datasheet states that COM must not be higher than V+ +0.3 V.

An analog switch like ISL43210A or similar can handle +15 V supply and the same voltage on the switched lines. And it is controllable by 5V logic without separate logic supply. Vishay, Rohm and many others have similar products.

[image]